VS Code extension i18n-ally pathMatcher kebab-case to camelCase
VS Code extension  i18n-ally
pathMatcher kebab-case to camelCase.
My i18 locales file directory name is kebab-case, but code namespace is camelCase.
I need to parsing automatic.....
Such as api-server/common.ts
Code is apiServer.xxxx
